# Cloudfront 502 Error on Lightsail (no recent changes to the website)

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lightsail

I have a website on AWS LightSail that uses CloudFront + free SSL from AWS.

Been working fine for a while now, didn't make any changes recently, however today it went down with '502 ERROR - The request could not be satisfied'.

Full error message:

> 502 ERROR
> The request could not be satisfied.
> CloudFront attempted to establish a connection with the origin, but either the attempt failed or the origin closed the connection. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
> If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.

Unfortunately, I'm not really experienced with AWS products and used Lightsail for the easy Wordpress setup, however now struggling to find the reason behind the breakdown and AWS support (paid) haven't replied yet. The website is down almost a day now and I'm really worried.

Could anyone advise how to debug the issue and fix it?

PS: I used a DNS Checker and it shows the CNAME records are down (A records a fine), know sure what to do about this though :(

Answer (score 0):

Feeling very stupid, but the solution was to reboot the Litghtsail instance. I know it's my fault for not realizing sooner the issue wasn't in the CDN but the origin itself, however the way AWS is communicating errors related to their products it's just a nightmare imo :(

Anyway, I guess we always learn something..